# How to downgrade Bootstrap 3 to 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, downgrade

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.2 but it can not run well on IE7,8 so I need to downgrade  it to version 2. How can I do that?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, go download the necessary files for version 2 (using http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ is likely going to be quite helpful) and set your site up to use those in place of the 3.x assets. This is a major-version change, so there's going to be breaking functionality all over the place. Things changed a lot from 2.x to 3.x, so you're going to have to make a lot of syntactic changes in your code to match the 2.x docs. There isn't a "downgrading" guide published, but the log at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per this article from Techrepublic it seems not possible : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bootstrap-3-says-mobile-first-everything-else-later/

**Not backward compatible**

> The reason the latest version is not backward compatible is a number
>   of class changes. The most notable changes include the removal of the
>   fluid classes (.container-fluid and .row-fluid) that were used to
>   build responsive interfaces. With Bootstrap 3.0.0, sites are
>   responsive by default, but there is an option to disable that feature.
>   Gone are the days of pixel width pages -- say hello to
>   percentage-based layouts going forward. Other changes that caused
>   problems include the removal of search form controls (.form-actions
>   and .form-search) and the .navbar-inner class.
>
> There are too many class changes to cover here, but the online
>   documentation provides all the necessary details as well as 3.0.0
>   equivalent features (where available). In addition, the official
>   Bootstrap blog post announcing the new version contains useful
>   information.