# Bootstrap and Javascript conflict issue in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have upgraded my one ASP.NET Core project from `VS2015` to `VS2017`. As a result, the jquery was upgraded from `2.2.3` to `3.2.1` and `Bootstrap` was upgraded from `3.3.6` to `3.3.7`. Now I'm getting the following error:

**Error**

> Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

**Snapshot of Error in Google Chrome's Dev Tool**:

[image]

On the other hand `VS2017` is not allowing me to downgrade Bootstrap from 3.3.6 to a version lower than 3 (also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30929469/1232087) why).

**Question**: How do I resolve the above issue? I'm stuck at the home page of the app where the issue occurs.

Comment: I saw this on a site I was working on when I was using bind() and unbind() that is not supported in JQ3. That may be what is happening happening with bs. https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.0/

Comment: @RegencySoftware I tried downgrading to `JQ 2.2.3` but can't downgrade `BS` to lower than 3.0 - and hence the issue is still there. But interesting to know that someone else has encountered a similar issue.

Comment: Huh, didn't you read the error message? The error message says that you need to downgrade **jQuery** to 2.x, **NOT** Bootstrap. when 3.3.7 can't work with jQuery 3, then 3.3.6 or 3..0 won't do it either since it's **older**.. **If anything** then you need to **upgrade** Bootstrap to i.e. 4.0 which is **newer** than 3.3.6 and may support jQuery 3

Comment: Just from the Bootstrap Website: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/ Bootstrap 4 Alpha does support/require jQuery 3.x

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the **jQuery** version is too new for Bootstrap 3.3.x to use.

You have two options:

1. Downgrade jQuery the latest 2.x version
2. Upgrade Bootstrap to 4.x (see [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/)) which requires to run on jQuery 3
3. Don't use the bootstrap.js at all and use `ngx-bootstrap` (only if you are using Angular >= 2, since it replaces the jQuery functions with a better integrated angular 2 directives)